# OpenLayers custom graphics per ModifyFeature

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm a beginning user of OpenLayers, but I want two different graphics (icons) for my ModifyFeatures.

I currently have an active DRAG-feature and RESIZE-feature, the drag should have a different icon than the resize.

I can set a graphic for both features with this:

```
new OpenLayers.Style({
    'externalGraphic': '/content/themes/base/imgs/mapdraw_move.png',
}
```

but then both features will be replaced with this images.

I already tried this (from a tutorial):

```
        OpenLayers.Control.DragGraphicFeature = OpenLayers.Class(
            OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature, {
                dragHandleStyle: null,
                initialize: function (layer, options) {
                    this.mode = OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.DRAG;
                    var init_style = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style.select);
                    this.dragHandleStyle = OpenLayers.Util.extend(init_style, {
                        externalGraphic: "/content/themes/base/imgs/mapdraw_resize.png",
                        fillOpacity: 1
                    });
                },
                CLASS_NAME: "OpenLayers.Control.DragGraphicFeature"
            });
```

but this had a negative result